# multiple selectors not working with context

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i'm trying to select some form elements when focusin and with this:

`$('textarea, input, select', '.highlightRow').live('focusin', function(e){ $(this).css("background-color","yellow"); });`

but there is something wrong with multiple selectors and context

when i use context and form don't have .highlightRow my textarea not change bgcolor (it's ok) but next elements in list (input, select) change bgcolor (it's wrong)

example: http://jsfiddle.net/RgEAw/1/

now only less elegant solution work ok:

`$('.highlightRow input, .highlightRow .highlightRow select, .highlightRow textarea')...`

is there any posibilities to use this multiple selector and context in this situation?

Comment: I don't see your .highlightRow in your html example, is it normal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), the context must be "a DOM Element, Document, or jQuery".  It cannot itself be a string selector.

So, when you specify this:

```
$('textarea, input, select', '.highlightRow')
```

you are apparently trying to specify a context of `'.highlightRow'` which is not one of the documented methods of specifying a context.  In this particular case, you can either get a single DOM element for `'.highlightRow'`, turn it into a jQuery object or put it into the actual selector.

But, context will ONLY work if the object you are passing actually exists.  If it doesn't exist, then it's like you're passing a NULL context which means to search the whole document so it doesn't do what you want.  So, you can only use the context parameter in the selector when it actually exists.

I would suggest using this:

```
$('.highlightRow textarea, .highlightRow input, .highlightRow select')
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/uzYuQ/.

Comment: Thanx for information about specyfing non existing context. If i use object in context efect is the same: http://jsfiddle.net/RgEAw/3/

Comment: maybe selector is ok but function realising highlighting is writen incorrectly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want exactly, but if you add class="hightlightRow" to the form, it seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/PYVMh/.  I added an additional event handler for blur() to remove the yellow background.   The second version above does not work when there is no class="highlightRow" because $('.highlightRow') doesn't evaluate to anything which means no context which means to allow anything in the document.  So, if you only want textarea, input and select tags that are inside a class="highlightRow", then use the first form above with the longer selector and no context.

Comment: Everything is ok when i want to highlight elements and use class="hightlightRow" but why in my code http://jsfiddle.net/RgEAw/3/ input and select are highlighted? There are no div/form with .higlightRow class. Generaly i would like to have one universal function for whole site - in few forms i must highligt row and i'm adding class="highlightRow", rest of forms without class="highlightRow" shouldn't highlighted at all.

Comment: A context ONLY works when the object you want to pass at the context EXISTS.  It doesn't work when it doesn't exist.  To work reliably, use this: `$('.highlightRow textarea, .highlightRow input, .highlightRow select')`.  As I said in my previous comment, this `$('textarea, input, select', $('.highlightRow'))` does not work properly when there is no class `highlightRow`.  See this jsFiddle for examples that both highlight and don't highlight: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/uzYuQ/.  Do it like you see there.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain better the option that will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information and exemples. In every piece of code that i crete i'm trying to use best, short and most efective method. In this situation i'll stay with $('.highlightRow textarea ... without context. I understand now that will not work when element used as context not exist in document. Previous i thougt that context to nonexist element protect from execute .live('focusin...

Comment: Yeah, I was confused by how the context works too, but in stepping through the code in jQuery, I can understand why it works the way it does.  There is something funky about the `textarea` element because it behaves different with an empty context than the other types of elements.  Maybe an abberation with how `.live()` works in jQuery.