# Multiple elements wired to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

if I have multiple elements which are wire certain function like

```
$('#one').change(function () {
    myFun();
});
$('#two').change(function () {
    myFun();
});
```

how can I do this with inline statement, I tried with

```
$('#one', '#tow').change()...
```

but that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: It's worth noting that `#tow` is not the same is `#two`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple selectors not working with context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395508/multiple-selectors-not-working-with-context)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For several selectors you can use comma (`,`), like this

```
$('#one, #tow').change()
```

[`multiple selector`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$('#one, #tow').change()...
```